# rails I have a background image in development environment this show but not in production

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

[CSS/HTML code snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD5hz.png)

In localhost I can see it perfectly but in a production environment, it is not loading.

I tried many forms but I haven't had good results.

Thank you,

Jhonny

Comment: Please post code directly instead of as images. Also, please describe your production environment. Also, the url of the image seems strange. Where in your project directory does it live? Also, this might help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

You give your code as image, so I cant modify it. But this will give you the idea.

**For `css`,**

first add `.scss` extension with your filename. so your file name should be like this,

```
filename.css.scss
```

Now, if you place your image in the `app/assets/images` folder you can access it like this,

```
background: url(asset-path("image.jpg"));
```

**for `html`,**

make sure your html file has the `.erb` extension with it. Then you can refer it with a small ruby block (assuming your image is in `app/assets/images` folder).

```
<%= asset_path "image.png" %>
```

Fot more info, you can read about [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).